What is the difference between capacitive liquid level sensor and potentiometer liquid level sensor
I have a sensor I use to determine the level of water in my swimming pool.  One person has told me it is a capacitive sensor and another said it works like a potentiometer.
I would like to know what the difference is between the two and what the one I am using is.  I am including an image of the one I am using.  Sorry but I have looked this up on the internet but any answers aren't very clear.


please edit your question ... add a link to the source of the image

That is what I would call a resistive-type sensor, so "potentiometer" is the more correct term here. Pool water has a low but non-zero resistance, and the more the electrodes are covered by water, the lower the resistance is between them. The (harmless*) current that passes through the water is amplified by the transistor and converted to a voltage signal by the "lower" 100 ohm resistor. I would expect a capacitive-type sensor to have a time-varying driving signal, which this one does not.
*To be safe, I do not recommend running this circuit off of a wall-powered supply unless you know what you are about re: isolation.

Based on the circuit schematic, your sensor is relying on dc (or constant) current flowing from the 5V supply, through the resistor, through the probes (plates?) and to the transistor base.  In air, this current is too small to turn on the transistor; however when placed in water that is sufficiently conductive (ie: is not pure water) then enough current flows to turn on the transistor.
So I would call this a resistance sensor:  its output depends on the resistance between the probes; if the resistance being sensed between the probes is low enough, the transistor turns on.  It could also be called a "conductance sensor", or "conductivity sensor", where conductance (conductivity) is just the inverse of resistance (resistivity).
If the circuit generated an AC signal (eg: a time varying voltage), and applied that AC signal to the probes, and used that AC signal to detect current passing between the probes, then possibly it might be called a capacitive (capacitance, or reactance) sensor.  But in that case, whether it was called "capacitive" or "resistive" would depend on details.
Some changes I may suggest:

Change the 100Ω going to the probe to something between 1kΩ and 10kΩ.  The probes don't need much current, and this prevents too much current flowing out of the 5V supply if some problem happens (like if the probes were to touch each other, or to touch earth).

Use a small battery to power this.  I would not trust a mains-powered 5V supply unless it was specifically designed and certified for operating in a pool environment.  Such devices require special isolation measures to ensure dangerous voltage cannot reach the user.



The whole thing is powered by batteries and the sensor is connected to an Arduino Pro mini.  I will try the 100k resistors.  It shouldn't affect the readings I get should it?  Thanks for the input.
